# WooCommerce shipping discount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a client that set up a site with WooCommerce and are processing tax exempt customers with a coupon code. The coupon applies a discount to amount using the same percentage as the sales tax essentially offsetting the amount.

the problem I have is they are also charging sales tax on shipping. The coupon will apply the discount to the items in the cart but not shipping. I need to make sure a discount is applied to shipping to offset the tax there is well. 
This is my first time looking under the hood of WooCommerce and could use some advice.

My first step has been to start with the woocommerce_before_cart_table hook to get applied coupons and totals. Just not sure were to go from there.

Again, any advice is greatly appreciated.

I should also point out there is no budget or time to go in and do a full tax exemption plugin. (Although I believe I may when I have time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the shipping rates and remove the taxes for tax exempt buyers.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_rates_to_remove_taxes', 10, 2 );

public function filter_rates_to_remove_taxes( $rates, $package ) {

// if buyer is tax exempt remove taxes from rates //


   return $rates;
}
```

And do tell client to pay for your services, he surely is out to make money with the site and you should treat this professionaly.

Comment: We did inevitably get them to invest in more than virtual duct tape and bungee cords.